# Rvm install ruby 2.2.0 on centos

Tags: ruby, centos, rvm

I get strange error while installing ruby 2.2.0 by rvm at centos 5.

Here is the log of installation:

```
[deployer@p241408 asiniy]$ rvm list
   ruby-2.1.0 [ i686 ]
=* ruby-2.1.1 [ i686 ]
```

I try to remove cache of previous installation:

```
[deployer@p241408 asiniy]$ rvm remove 2.2.0
ruby-2.2.0 - #removing src/ruby-2.2.0..
```

Reset RVM & install

```
[deployer@p241408 asiniy]$ rvm reset
[deployer@p241408 asiniy]$ rvm install 2.2
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: centos/5/i386/ruby-2.2.0.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for centos.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.2.0 - #downloading ruby-2.2.0, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.2.0 - #extracting ruby-2.2.0 to /home/deployer/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.0....
ruby-2.2.0 - #applying patch /home/deployer/.rvm/patches/ruby/2.2.0/fix_installing_bundled_gems.patch.
ruby-2.2.0 - #configuring.........................................................
ruby-2.2.0 - #post-configuration..
ruby-2.2.0 - #compiling..............
Error running '__rvm_make -j1',
showing last 15 lines of /home/deployer/.rvm/log/1425194973_ruby-2.2.0/make.log
            (use (reg:SI 19 dirflag))
        ]) 528 {*rep_movsi} (insn_list:REG_DEP_TRUE 8516 (insn_list:REG_DEP_TRUE 8521 (insn_list:REG_DEP_TRUE 8522 (nil))))
    (expr_list:REG_UNUSED (reg/f:SI 2548 [ block ])
        (expr_list:REG_UNUSED (reg/f:SI 2547 [ proc ])
            (expr_list:REG_UNUSED (reg:SI 2 cx [2550])
                (expr_list:REG_DEAD (reg:SI 19 dirflag)
                    (expr_list:REG_DEAD (reg/v/f:SI 1033 [ blockptr ])
                        (expr_list:REG_DEAD (reg:SI 2 cx [2549])
                            (expr_list:REG_UNUSED (reg/f:SI 2548 [ block ])
                                (expr_list:REG_UNUSED (reg/f:SI 2547 [ proc ])
                                    (expr_list:REG_UNUSED (reg:SI 2 cx [2550])
                                        (nil)))))))))))
vm_exec.c:127: confused by earlier errors, bailing out
make: *** [vm.o] Error 1
++ return 2
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

Here is the whole error from log file:

```
[deployer@p241408 ~]$ tail -n 200 /home/deployer/.rvm/log/1425194973_ruby-2.2.0/make.log
[2015-03-01 02:33:04] __rvm_make
__rvm_make () 
{ 
    \make "$@" || return $?
}
current path: /home/deployer/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.0
PATH=/home/deployer/.rvm/usr/bin:/home/deployer/.rvm/bin:/home/deployer/bin:/home/deployer/bin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/home/deployer/bin
command(2): __rvm_make -j1
++ make -j1
    CC = gcc
    LD = ld
    LDSHARED = gcc -shared
    CFLAGS = -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -std=iso9899:1999 -fPIC -march=i486
    XCFLAGS = -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -fvisibility=hidden -DRUBY_EXPORT
    CPPFLAGS =   -I. -I.ext/include/i686-linux -I./include -I.
    DLDFLAGS = -Wl,-soname,libruby.so.2.2  -fstack-protector  -march=i486
    SOLIBS = -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm  
Using built-in specs.
Target: i386-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --disable-plugin --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.4.2-gcj-1.4.2.0/jre --with-cpu=generic --host=i386-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)
compiling main.c
compiling dmydln.c
compiling miniinit.c
compiling miniprelude.c
copying dummy probes.h
compiling array.c
compiling bignum.c
compiling class.c
class.c: In function ‘rewrite_cref_stack’:
class.c:238: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
class.c: In function ‘clone_method’:
class.c:260: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
compiling compar.c
compiling complex.c
compiling dir.c
compiling dln_find.c
compiling encoding.c
compiling enum.c
enum.c: In function ‘sort_by_i’:
enum.c:840: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
enum.c: In function ‘enum_sort_by’:
enum.c:974: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
compiling enumerator.c
compiling error.c
compiling eval.c
compiling load.c
compiling proc.c
compiling file.c
compiling gc.c
compiling hash.c
compiling inits.c
compiling io.c
compiling marshal.c
compiling math.c
compiling node.c
compiling numeric.c
compiling object.c
compiling pack.c
compiling parse.c
compiling process.c
compiling random.c
compiling range.c
compiling rational.c
compiling re.c
compiling regcomp.c
compiling regenc.c
compiling regerror.c
compiling regexec.c
compiling regparse.c
compiling regsyntax.c
compiling ruby.c
compiling safe.c
compiling signal.c
compiling sprintf.c
In file included from sprintf.c:1255:
vsnprintf.c: In function ‘BSD_vfprintf’:
vsnprintf.c:822: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false
compiling st.c
compiling strftime.c
compiling string.c
compiling struct.c
compiling symbol.c
compiling time.c
compiling transcode.c
compiling util.c
compiling variable.c
compiling version.c
compiling compile.c
compiling debug.c
compiling iseq.c
iseq.c: In function ‘set_relation’:
iseq.c:228: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
iseq.c:235: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
iseq.c:236: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
iseq.c:241: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
iseq.c:247: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
iseq.c: In function ‘rb_iseq_clone’:
iseq.c:1977: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
iseq.c:1981: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
compiling vm.c
In file included from vm.c:77:
vm_insnhelper.c: In function ‘vm_cref_push’:
vm_insnhelper.c:276: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
vm_insnhelper.c:279: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
In file included from vm_exec.c:120,
                 from vm.c:79:
insns.def: In function ‘vm_exec_core’:
insns.def:994: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
In file included from vm.c:82:
vm_eval.c: In function ‘eval_string_with_cref’:
vm_eval.c:1281: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
vm.c: In function ‘vm_define_method’:
vm.c:2260: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
vm_exec.c: In function ‘vm_exec_core’:
vm_exec.c:127: error: unable to find a register to spill in class ‘SIREG’
vm_exec.c:127: error: this is the insn:
(insn:HI 8524 8522 8525 1038 vm.c:644 (parallel [
            (set (reg:SI 2 cx [2550])
                (const_int 0 [0x0]))
            (set (reg/f:SI 2547 [ proc ])
                (plus:SI (ashift:SI (reg:SI 2 cx [2549])
                        (const_int 2 [0x2]))
                    (reg:SI 5 di [orig:1030 D.47274 ] [1030])))
            (set (reg/f:SI 2548 [ block ])
                (plus:SI (ashift:SI (reg:SI 2 cx [2549])
                        (const_int 2 [0x2]))
                    (reg/v/f:SI 1033 [ blockptr ])))
            (set (mem/s:BLK (reg:SI 5 di [orig:1030 D.47274 ] [1030]) [13 <variable>.block+0 S20 A32])
                (mem/s:BLK (reg/v/f:SI 1033 [ blockptr ]) [13 S20 A32]))
            (use (reg:SI 2 cx [2549]))
            (use (reg:SI 19 dirflag))
        ]) 528 {*rep_movsi} (insn_list:REG_DEP_TRUE 8516 (insn_list:REG_DEP_TRUE 8521 (insn_list:REG_DEP_TRUE 8522 (nil))))
    (expr_list:REG_UNUSED (reg/f:SI 2548 [ block ])
        (expr_list:REG_UNUSED (reg/f:SI 2547 [ proc ])
            (expr_list:REG_UNUSED (reg:SI 2 cx [2550])
                (expr_list:REG_DEAD (reg:SI 19 dirflag)
                    (expr_list:REG_DEAD (reg/v/f:SI 1033 [ blockptr ])
                        (expr_list:REG_DEAD (reg:SI 2 cx [2549])
                            (expr_list:REG_UNUSED (reg/f:SI 2548 [ block ])
                                (expr_list:REG_UNUSED (reg/f:SI 2547 [ proc ])
                                    (expr_list:REG_UNUSED (reg:SI 2 cx [2550])
                                        (nil)))))))))))
vm_exec.c:127: confused by earlier errors, bailing out
make: *** [vm.o] Error 1
++ return 2
```

Comment: show whole error from `/home/deployer/.rvm/log/1425194973_ruby-2.2.0/make.log`

Comment: @mpapis done 150 lines

Comment: do you have `CFLAGS` set? -> run: `env | grep FLAGS=`.

Comment: No, I haven't. command return nothing

Comment: Im currently on 2.2.1 on Redhat 5 and now encountering this problem when compiling Ruby 2.3.1, have you solved this problem for 2.3.x?

Comment: @WestonGanger switch to debian :D Seriously, there was a bug in 2.2.0 I discussed with Michal Papis. Now I'm not interested in a ruby a lot, so, I think I can't help you. Sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution is very simple. Instead of trying to install `2.2.0`, I've installed just released version `2.2.1`.

So,

```
rvm install 2.2.1
```

Answer (score 0):

this looks like a bug in ruby itself, report it here: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-trunk/issues 
also try with `ruby-head` - and include the results in the report.

Comment: it's the development code for ruby, you can install it in RVM using exactly: `rvm install ruby-head` - most likely it will show the same bug - unless it's fixed in master and only needs backporting to `2.2`